# mySQLi Query not giving correct information

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I made this script:

```
$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = sha1($_POST["password"]);
$checkuser_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
$checkuser = mysqli_num_rows($checkuser_query);
$checkactive_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND verified='0'");
$checkactive = mysqli_num_rows($checkactive_query);
$checkbanned_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND closed='1'");
$checkbanned = mysqli_num_rows($checkactive_query);
if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"])) {
    header("Location: http://empirebattles.co.uk/Login?alert=nofilled");
}
elseif($checkuser<= 0) {
    header("location: http://empirebattles.co.uk/Login?alert=loginfailed");
}
elseif($checkactive==1) {
    header("location: http://empirebattles.co.uk/Login?alert=unverified");
}
elseif($checkbanned==1) {
    header("location: http://empirebattles.co.uk/Login?alert=banned");
}       
else {
    header("Location: http://empirebattles.co.uk/Home");
    setcookie("EmpireBattles",$username,time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60),"/");
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE users SET online = '1' WHERE username = '$username'");
}
```

And, it works. Up until the point where it redirects you if you are banned. It just skips it , even if you are banned.

I've had a look, googled it and even asked my teacher, nobody can see what's wrong.

Please have a look,
Tom.

Comment: is checkactive_query defined?

Comment: Yes. See my latest edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing this line:

```
  $checkbanned = mysqli_num_rows($checkactive_query);
```

to

```
  $checkbanned = mysqli_num_rows($checkbanned_query );
```

Comment: Ah. Thank you. I didn't spot that.